# Hibernate Query filter by Regex expression

Tags: java, mysql, regex, hibernate, hql

I have an entity which has a pattern column. What would be the best way to find an existing record based on which pattern matches a given string?

For example:

#### Table records

```
| ID | pattern |
| 1  | /actions/{action-id:\d+}/{type-id:\d+}/{edge:[a-z][\w]+}/draft |,
| 2  | /actions/{action-id:\d+}/{edge:[a-z][\w]+}/submit |,
| 3  | /actions/{action-id:\d+}/{type-id:\d+}/{edge:[a-z][\w]+}/request |,
| 4  | /actions/{action-id:\d+}/{edge:[a-z][\w]+}/request |,
| 5  | /actions/{action-id:\d+}/{edge:[a-z][\w]+}/terminate |
```

#### Input String

```
/actions/1/send/request
```

This would return the `Action` record with `ID = 4` as the pattern `/actions/{action-id:\d+}/{edge:[a-z][\w]+}/request` matches the input string.

Which is the most perfomant way to achieve this?

> Note: It's guaranteed that the input string will match **only one**
>   pattern in the table

.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add SQL Restriction like this

```
Criteria criteria ...

criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(theInputString+" REGEXP pattern")
```